# accessing the local database in all the pages of the WP app

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I am following the example from [Local Database for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202865%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). From it, I learned how to create a local database in my app and pull a data to a page.

What I am looking for now is to show the data not in one page but three pages of my app. So, what are my ways to do this? Can I make an object in app.xaml and access it in the pages?

Kindly advise me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The approaches all boil down to your views on the architecture and how testable you want your application to be.

Whilst you *could* put some reference to the data context on your application object, you're then increasing the linkage between the view-models and the views; Arguably nothing in the view-models needs to know anything about anything in the views (and I'm in the camp where all xaml counts as part of the views). With this in mind, one alternate would be to have something in your view-models (or even your models) that is a static class that exposes application level objects (in a manner that is unit-test friendly, and perhaps even sharable amongst platforms) and allows any of your view-models access to that datacontext and construct any of your models, etc.